# How to close file after the following code exits

Tags: c#

The following code causes my input file to remain locked. I need to figure out how to release the file after the image is drawn. I call the draw wave form and it creates a bmp for the sinewave but it locks the file causing a file in use error. Any Ideas on how to close the file after it done drawing. To make it simple I added a button show exactly what I am doing. I still get the file in use error. Sorry I have added the float array code to the beginning also it is a win form using vs2017 the float array is in the same code as the LoadwaveForm code

```
    public float[] FloatArrayFromStream(System.IO.MemoryStream stream)
    {
        return FloatArrayFromByteArray(stream.GetBuffer());
    }

    public float[] FloatArrayFromByteArray(byte[] input)
    {
        float[] output = new float[input.Length / 4];
        for (int i = 0; i < output.Length; i++)
        {
            output[i] = BitConverter.ToSingle(input, i * 4);
        }
        return output;
    }
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (open.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK) return;
        if (!open.FileName.EndsWith(".mp3")) { return; }
        String FilePath = open.FileName;
        LoadWaveForm(FilePath);
        File.Delete(FilePath);
    }

 private void LoadWaveForm(String MP3FilePath)
    {
        string strPath = MP3FilePath;
        string SongID = "2";
        byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(strPath);
        WriteToFile(SongID, strPath, bytes);
    }

    private void WriteToFile(string SongID, string strPath, byte[] Buffer)
    {
        try
        {
            int samplesPerPixel = 128;
            long startPosition = 0;
            float[] data = FloatArrayFromByteArray(Buffer);

            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(594, 92);

            int BORDER_WIDTH = 5;
            int width = bmp.Width - (2 * BORDER_WIDTH);
            int height = bmp.Height - (2 * BORDER_WIDTH);

            NAudio.Wave.Mp3FileReader reader = new NAudio.Wave.Mp3FileReader(strPath, wf => new NAudio.FileFormats.Mp3.DmoMp3FrameDecompressor(wf));
            NAudio.Wave.WaveChannel32 channelStream = new NAudio.Wave.WaveChannel32(reader);

            int bytesPerSample = (reader.WaveFormat.BitsPerSample / 8) * channelStream.WaveFormat.Channels;

            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
            {

                g.Clear(Color.White);
                Pen pen1 = new Pen(Color.Gray);
                int size = data.Length;

                string hexValue1 = "#009adf";
                Color colour1 = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(hexValue1);
                pen1.Color = colour1;

                Stream wavestream = new NAudio.Wave.Mp3FileReader(strPath, wf => new NAudio.FileFormats.Mp3.DmoMp3FrameDecompressor(wf));

                wavestream.Position = 0;
                int bytesRead1;
                byte[] waveData1 = new byte[samplesPerPixel * bytesPerSample];
                wavestream.Position = startPosition + (width * bytesPerSample * samplesPerPixel);

                for (float x = 0; x < width; x++)
                {
                    short low = 0;
                    short high = 0;
                    bytesRead1 = wavestream.Read(waveData1, 0, samplesPerPixel * bytesPerSample);
                    if (bytesRead1 == 0)
                        break;
                    for (int n = 0; n < bytesRead1; n += 2)
                    {
                        short sample = BitConverter.ToInt16(waveData1, n);
                        if (sample < low) low = sample;
                        if (sample > high) high = sample;
                    }
                    float lowPercent = ((((float)low) - short.MinValue) / ushort.MaxValue);
                    float highPercent = ((((float)high) - short.MinValue) / ushort.MaxValue);
                    float lowValue = height * lowPercent;
                    float highValue = height * highPercent;
                    g.DrawLine(pen1, x, lowValue, x, highValue);
                }

            }

            pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
        }
        catch
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: According to the Microsoft docs [File.ReadAllBytes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readallbytes?view=netframework-4.7.2): "Opens a binary file, reads the contents of the file into a byte array, and then **closes the file**.". So, maybe there is another problem?. What is the error message and where does the error occur?

Comment: I am taking a mp3 file and trimming the begging and the end with no problem but when I go to move the file or delete it I get the file in use error. That being said I eliminated the code above and I can delete or move it as long as I don't the Loadwave procedure.

Comment: LoadWaveForm(FilePath);
File.Delete(FilePath); If I eliminate the first line I can delete the file; with it I get a file in use error

Comment: I figured out how to show you the actual error maybe this will help. System.IO.IOException
  HResult=0x80070020
  Message=The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\TattleTale\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\YoutubeDownloader\YoutubeDownloader\bin\Debug\MP3s\LEAD ME ON.mp3' because it is being used by another process.
  Source=mscorlib

Comment: Sorry - I created a solution with your software but I don't have the library that has the `NAudio` class. Also can't figure out where the `FloatArrayFromByteArray` method (?) comes from. Did you install or are you referencing an NAudio class (maybe a DLL file)? Where did you get it from?

Comment: Also, can you put a debugger on your code? Which line of code is causing the `System.IO.IOException`?

Comment: Is this a Winforms project, or a Universal Windows app project?

Comment: I figured it out as dumb as it may sound I had to save the bmp as shown below  pictureBox1.Image = bmp;                                                 bmp.Save("TrimMp3.bmp");

Comment: Thanks for all your help Nova Sys Eng. it was truly appreciated.

Comment: Try calling `channelStream.Dispose();` and `reader.Dispose();` in `WriteToFile(...)`-s body.